# docker using btrfs on lvm2 mount

Tags: docker, btrfs, lvm2, synology-diskstation

I've modified my synology DS918 (DSM 6.2.2-24922 Update 4) to run docker-19.03.8. Unfortunately, while the main mount `/volume1` is btrfs, and docker supports `btrfs` as a storage driver, it

> *requires a dedicated block storage device such as a physical disk*
>
> - https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/btrfs-driver/

Synology defaults to using LVM2 (I think) underneath:

```
root@nas1:~# docker info 2> /dev/null | grep -i root
 Docker Root Dir: /volume1/@docker
root@nas1:~# mount | grep ' /volume1 '
/dev/mapper/vg1-volume_1 on /volume1 type btrfs (rw,relatime,synoacl,space_cache=v2,auto_reclaim_space,metadata_ratio=50,subvolid=257,subvol=/@syno)
```

I cannot pull any images, due to this (using `traefik` as an example, this is universal):

```
root@nas1:~# docker pull traefik:v2.2
v2.2: Pulling from library/traefik
aad63a933944: Pull complete
f365f1b91ebb: Extracting [==================================================>]  694.1kB/694.1kB
dc367a6045f5: Download complete
ff697159d003: Download complete
failed to register layer: Failed to create btrfs snapshot: inappropriate ioctl for device
```

which suggests that the underlying problem is with btrfs snapshots/subvolumes (though I don't know much about how to work with or manipulate them).

Questions:

1. **Can `docker` be made to work with btrfs-on-lvm2?** I've tried changing to `"storage-driver":"devicemapper"` (and `"overlay2"`), no luck (dockerd won't start). Nothing else in the docker-ce docs suggest other mechanisms.
2. **Is there a way to get Synology to mount `/volume1` on a non-LVM2 partition?** It's mirrored (RAID-1) 8TB drives with some exported shares.